# Securing a wcf service with two end points

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a simple service with two end points on wcf 3.5. One is a web service using wshttpBinding while the other is exposing a rest service (webHttpbinding). 
They work fine but now I want to add windows authentication to the webservice. I have created a config file as follows:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>    
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="restBinding">

    </binding>             
  </webHttpBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsBinding">         
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                 negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                 algorithmSuite="Default"
                 establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>      
   </wsHttpBinding>

</bindings>
<behaviors>   
  <serviceBehaviors>      
    <behavior name="WcfRestService3.WsServiceHostBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfRestService3.WsServiceHostBehavior" name="WcfRestService3.ServiceImpl">
    <endpoint name="wsConnection" address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding" contract="WcfRestService3.IService" />      
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />-->
    <endpoint name="restConnection" address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="restBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" contract="WcfRestService3.IService" />
  </service>




</services>    

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

On IIS I have enabled windows authentication and anonymous auth: and I can freely access the service.. 
When I disable the anonymous auth i get the following error:

```
Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to add authentication to both endpoints or only to WsHttpEndpoint.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to add authentication to wsHttpEndpoint. But if thats not possible securing both endpoints is Ok

Comment: But in such case setting message security with Windows authentication is enough. You don't need to change configuration of IIS.